# how to set components invisible in netbeans drag and drop design view

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to set components invisible in the netbeans design view and then show then from coding when some event occurs. Is it possible?

Comment: are you talking about `JFrameForm` ? in NetBeans

Comment: yes i am talking about the JFrameForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `NewJFrameForm` using Netbeans, In Design view you can drag and drop all the components available in palette.

In order to set initially invisible / hidden at starting you have to do it manually.
Click on source above, Now you can see generated source of that frame you designed.
You will see constructor as:

```
public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
```

Generated itself.
now you have to put your own code to update like in my case i will set invisible my compnents like:

```
jPanel1.setVisible(false);
```

**OR**

specific components:

```
jButton1.setVisible(false);
jToggleButton1.setVisible(false);
jLabel1.setVisible(false);
```

if prefer this like:

```
public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        mySettings();
    }
public void mySettings(){
//Hide or set initial Values of components
}
```

[image]

**Note:**

all your generated code is in

```
    initComponents();
```

you can not edit it in source, have to do it in design view

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i actually did the same but it seemed little akward to first setting components visible from the design view and then setting it invisible in the constructor. Ok if this method is a standard one then I will stick to it.
Thank you

Comment: @viper Yup it is recommended way because in design view you should see all your available components at least. If hidden you can not recognize the place and position and if any other person sees your code it is very complex.
If this question helped you please mark it accept and vote up as per policy thanks